# Override or change GoDaddy website description? Not working with meta tags

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, meta

I host my website on AWS S3 and utilize Route 53 to assign my domain name bought from GoDaddy. My issue is that the description of the site which appears in search engine results is the one I originally wrote (I believe) when registering the domain with GoDaddy. Updating the  tag does not change the description.

I cannot find a way to either override the GoDaddy description with my own html or how to edit it (without using their WebsiteBuilder, which I have not purchased). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to modify the files within the S3 bucket. The index file is your "homepage" -- this is defined in your S3 bucket configuration (probably index.html)

You'll need to modify the following HTML elements to the title and description you'd like to appear in search results:

```
<title>This is the Title of my Website</title>
<meta name="description" content="This is the longer description of my website that appears in a Google search result.">
```

If these tags are already correct then Google could be choosing a title for your site based on external links and the link text used in those links for certain queries (such as your brand name).

**=== EDIT 01/09/2017 ===**

Adding a screenshot of what I see in a Google search:
[image: google search result]

This seems to line up exactly with the tags I see implemented in your HTML source:

```
<title>Cameron Cabo</title>
<meta name="description" content="Personal website of designer, artist, and future engineer and businessman Cameron Cabo. Cameron studies Computer Science and Management in the Jerome Fisher Program at the University of Pennsylvania. He is also passionate about art, design, and creative innovation.">
```

Comment: This is the same case for search engines other than google (I've checked bing, yahoo, and ecosia), so I think the issue is slightly more complex than simply "choosing" one description over the other

Comment: Any chance you can share the url for review @CameronCabo. It might be easier to spot the issue if you're seeing different results than the title and meta description tags.

Comment: OK. I see you have the following title and meta[description] elements:

`<title>Cameron Cabo</title><meta name="description" content="Personal website of designer, artist, and future engineer and businessman Cameron Cabo. Cameron studies Computer Science and Management in the Jerome Fisher Program at the University of Pennsylvania. He is also passionate about art, design, and creative innovation." />`

When I do a google search these do appear to be showing up in search exactly as written. Where is it that you're not seeing them rendering as implemented?

Comment: It seems that the description took a day or so to update on Google. Thank you for the help.